# Visual studio the project needs to be deployed before it can be started

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-phone, windows-mobile, windows-phone-8-emulator

When starting to test the application on Windows Phone (even a blank app) on emulator or device, this error is poping out "The project needs to be deployed before it can be started". "verify the project is selected  to be deployed in the solution configuration manager, or depoly it explicitly by clicking one of the deploy commands in the Build menu" The emulator will be started & run successfully, still no luck in deploying app on emulator.

[image]2>Error: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Probably the reason for this is that your `Build` and `Deploy` configurations aren't enabled. To enable these configurations. Do these steps:

Step 1: Open the Configuration Manager by clicking the active solution configuration. The default is `<Debug>`:

[image]

Step 2: Enable the `Build` and `Deploy` configurations by checking the boxes for `Any CPU`.
[image]

After this, you can try running you app. It should be working properly.

Comment: What is your selected solution platform?

Comment: selected solution platform Any CPU

Comment: all of this has been enabled for me by default, I still get the error...

Comment: @mindOfAi Your suggestion worked for me (thank you).

Comment: when you want mobile anyCPU is grey out and still want to deploy :(

Comment: It was already selected by default, yet I keep getting the error. Wasn't able to do anything productive with MAUI so far

Comment: Avoid spaces in project names

Comment: For those still getting error, check 'Package.appxmanifest' by double clicking on it.

Comment: @Auto Where is this file and what are we looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this would possibly be either one of the following:

1. Checking in the Debug & Build tick marks in the configuration manager (from Debug -> Config Manager -> Debug & Build) which works in most of the time.
2. Cross checking the deployment environment with the file systems and everything (Windows/Android/ios). This can be checked from the drop down menu.

However, in some cases everything might be in the right place (having the checked in build & deploy, choosing the right managers) in my case what worked for me the naming convention. When I created the project, i was using the wrong convention. (Maybe we have to follow platform specific naming conventions). You can view it here in the following
[link](https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui/blob/main/docs/migration/multi-project-to-single-project.md).

Answer (score 0):

One of possible errors is incomplete or partially complete Package.appxmanifest. Check the file. I had a red X next to an incomplete field.

Comment: Where is this file supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error

```
Error       DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073D1F] Deployment operation failed.
```

I added en-us as the language in Package.appxmanifest, but that did not fix the problem. Both 'Build' and 'Deploy' were already tagged by default.

I moved the app to a local drive, as opposed to a server shared drive, and then it deployed and ran OK